# using the GetIndex() function

Tags: python, mysql, wxpython, mysql-python

Managed to fix up my code. now thing is I'm trying to call up an event to use the getIndex() to extract the index of the currently selected listctrl item. I know I need to pass a varable for event but the code keeps moaning on me having to declare it.. or if I actually use event in the evt_itemselected binding.. it says I have no such varable named event.... can't seem to find any examples for situations like this... can somebldy please enlighten me?

```
from wx import *
import Customer as c
class CustomerMain ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Customers", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 517,486 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( -1,-1 ), wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer3 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )


        # Create a customer
        self.cust = c.Customer()



        self.list = wx.ListCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize,wx.LC_REPORT )
        self.list.InsertColumn(0,"ID")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1,"First Name")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2,"Last Name")
        self.list.Bind(EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED,self.SelItem())
        self.list.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 500,300 ) )
        self.list.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 1000,800 ) )
        self.refresh_list(None)

        bSizer3.Add( self.list, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 5 )

        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        self.m_button20 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Add Customer", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button20.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_entry)
        bSizer4.Add( self.m_button20, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

        self.m_button21 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Update Record", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_button21.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.update_entry())
        bSizer4.Add( self.m_button21, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL, 5 )





        bSizer3.Add( bSizer4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.SetSizer( bSizer3 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )
        self.Show()

    def refresh_list(self, event):
        """Place the names of each CustomerEntry into the list"""

        index = 0
        self.entrydict = {}
        self.list.DeleteAllItems()
        for entry in self.cust.list_entries():
            self.list.InsertStringItem(index,entry.Cust_ID)
            self.list.SetStringItem(index,1,entry.F_Name)
            self.list.SetStringItem(index,2,entry.L_Name)
            self.entrydict[index] = entry
            index += 1

    def SelItem (self, event):
        """""Extracts the index of the currently selected listctrl item"""
        currentItem = self.list.GetIndex()
        return currentItem

    def add_entry(self, event):
       """Add a new entry to the Address cust"""
       # start out with blank, generic CustomerEntry
       entry = c.CustomerEntry("","","","","")
       self.endiag = CustomerDetail(self,entry)
       self.endiag.ShowModal()           



       self.cust.add_entry(entry.Cust_ID,
                            entry.F_Name,
                            entry.L_Name,
                            entry.Address,
                            entry.Cust_Stat )

       self.refresh_list(None)

    def update_entry(self, event):
       entry = self.entrydict[self.list.GetItemData(self.selItem)]
       self.endiag2 = CustomerDetail(self , entry)
       self.endiag2.Show()
       self.refresh_list(entry)

  def __del__( self ):
      pass


  class CustomerDetail ( wx.Dialog ):

    def __init__( self, parent, entry ):
            wx.Dialog.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 690,500 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE )

            self.entry = entry
            self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 500,500 ), wx.DefaultSize )

            bSizer6 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

            gSizer6 = wx.GridSizer( 2, 2, 0, 0 )

            self.m_staticText5 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ID", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText5.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText5, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Cust_ID = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Cust_ID.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.Cust_ID.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_ID, 1, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_staticText6 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"First Name", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText6.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText6, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.F_Name = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.F_Name.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.F_Name.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.F_Name, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_staticText7 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Last Name", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText7.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText7, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.L_Name = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.L_Name.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.L_Name.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.L_Name, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_staticText8 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Address", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText8.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText8, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.Address = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.Address.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.Address.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 500,15 ) )

            gSizer6.Add( self.Address, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.m_staticText12 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Status", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_staticText12.Wrap( -1 )
            gSizer6.Add( self.m_staticText12, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )


            stat_choices = ["Active","Inactive","Archived"]

            self.Cust_Stat = wx.ComboBox( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, stat_choices, 0 )
            self.Cust_Stat.SetMinSize( wx.Size( 200,15 ) )
            self.Cust_Stat.SetMaxSize( wx.Size( 300,15 ) )
            self.Cust_Stat.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.OnSelect)
            gSizer6.Add( self.Cust_Stat, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

            bSizer6.Add( gSizer6, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            bSizer13 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

            self.m_button24 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"ok", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button24.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.ok)

            bSizer13.Add( self.m_button24, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            self.m_button25 = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"cancel", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
            self.m_button25.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closeDial)

            bSizer13.Add( self.m_button25, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5 )

            bSizer6.Add( bSizer13, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )

            self.SetSizer( bSizer6 )
            self.Layout()

            self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def OnSelect (self, event):
        self.Cust_Stat.GetValue()



    def closeDial(self,event):

        self.Destroy()


    def ok(self, event):
        self.entry.set_details( str(self.Cust_ID.GetValue()),
                            str(self.F_Name.GetValue()),
                            str(self.L_Name.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Address.GetValue()),
                            str(self.Cust_Stat.GetValue()) )
        self.Destroy()


       def __del__( self ):
               pass                
  def main():


   ex = wx.App()
   CustomerMain(None)
   ex.MainLoop()
```

if **name** == '**main**':
       main()

Comment: `_Which sets the details of the entry object, returns entry object and calls a function to close the window and pass a bool parameter for executing the adding of said object both to the SQL database and listctrl widget_` - O.o - you need to refactor this

Comment: I want to execute this particular code segment once the window is closed
'
if self.endiag.closeOK == True:

               self.cust.add_entry(entry.Cust_ID,
                            entry.F_Name,
                            entry.L_Name,
                            entry.Address,
                            entry.Cust_Stat )

               self.refresh_list(None) '

so the closeOK returns a true bool to trigger it on window close... or so I thought

Comment: okay so I placed closeOK and close dial before the return statement. thing is I know it never sends the data as the thing closes prematurely before the entry object can be returned... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in section of the code:

```
  return self.entry
  self.closeOK
  self.CloseDial
```

closeOk and CloseDial are never called because they are after the return statement.